# New object instance with DI in constructor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m new to Inonic/Angular.

My question is, I have this class that I’ve created which uses DI:

```
import { HttpServiceProvider } from './../providers/http-service/http-service';

export class HttpWrapper{

    private _url: string;
    private _port: number;
    private _api: string;
    private _headers: Map<string, string>;

    constructor(private httpServie: HttpServiceProvider, url: string, port: number, api: string){
        this.url = url;
        this.port = port;
        this.api = api;
    }
```

When I want to create a new instance of this class I need to provide ‘HttpServiceProvider’ to the constructor. What is the right way to initiate new object of this kind? (without providing the ‘HttpServiceProvider’).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a `parameter` of a class with `null` then it will not give you `error` on initialization of new `Object`

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
export class HttpWrapper {

    private _url: string;
    private _port: number;
    private _api: string;
    private _headers: Map<string, string>;

    constructor(private httpServie: HttpServiceProvider = null, url: string, port: number, api: string){
        this.url = url;
        this.port = port;
        this.api = api;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also make a parameter optional like this:

```js
export class HttpWrapper {

    private _url: string;
    private _port: number;
    private _api: string;
    private _headers: Map<string, string>;

    constructor(url: string, port: number, api: string, private httpServie?: HttpServiceProvider){
        this.url = url;
        this.port = port;
        this.api = api;
    }
```

Here is example: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-as81x1?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: I still need to pass it to the constructor.

Comment: its undefined in that way